# symfony2 override the service security.authentication.manager

Tags: symfony

I would like to add some code inside the function authenticate() of the Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager.

I tried to create a child bundle of the security bundle.
And i redefined the service for security.authentication.manager in this bundle like that

```
    <!-- Authentication related services -->
    <service id="security.authentication.manager" class="%security.authentication.manager.class%" public="false">
        <argument type="collection" />
    </service>
```

But when i relad the page, the framework throw an exception: InvalidArgumentException: You must at least add one authentication provider.

I suppose it's becaue the dependecies are created inside the parent bundle configuation.

What i must do to get it work without redefine the whole security bundle ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found that the best way is to create my own a factory, that extends the formFactory of symfony2

Then i must create my own AuthentificationProvider that extend the DaoAuthenticationProvider and declare it as abstract service.

Then create the service inside the factory via the method createAuthProvider() and replace the parameters we need.

```
protected function createAuthProvider(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProviderId)
{
    $provider = 'acme.authentication.provider.dao.'.$id;
    $container
        ->setDefinition($provider, new DefinitionDecorator('acme.authentication.provider.dao'))
        ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProviderId))//replace args on the service constructor
        ->replaceArgument(2, $id)
        ->addArgument(new Reference('acme.api'))//add some args to the service constructor
    ;

    return $provider;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that better would be created your own handlers.

1. You need to create [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/glossary.html#term-service)
2. Register it into [service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).
3. Simply set handlers in your [`security.yml`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html):

```
form_login:
    success_handler: success_login_handler
    failure_handler: failure_login_handler
logout:
    success_handler: success_logout_handler
```

Comment: In fact i need to make some verification before the user is logged in. I need to call an external api, and test credentials, then if user account exists(on external api and in local database) i can authorize access to user.

Comment: If you load users from local DB, can you do that job in [`EntityRepository`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider)?

Comment: This is the problem, In fact i want to use the login form to search first on the api to find users (not in db) and will sync them with DB if the external login return a user.

For that reason, i nedd to be able to add some custom test in the authentification method(), But i really do not know how to correctly override the SecurityBundle